# How to print two PSCustomObject sequentially?

Tags: powershell

I need to display FSMO information using Powershell

```
$first = $(Get-ADDomain | Select-Object InfrastructureMaster, RIDMaster, PDCEmulator)
$second = $(Get-ADForest | Select-Object DomainNamingMaster, SchemaMaster)
```

And when i try to print `$first` and `$second` variables sequentially, script prints only the first variable.

In this way prints only `$first`

```
$first = $(Get-ADDomain | Select-Object InfrastructureMaster, RIDMaster, PDCEmulator
$second = $(Get-ADForest | Select-Object DomainNamingMaster, SchemaMaster)
echo $first
echo $second
```

The output:

```
InfrastructureMaster RIDMaster        PDCEmulator
-------------------- ---------        -----------
ad-srv.cma.local     ad-srv.cma.local ad-srv.cma.local
```

But when I swap the echo commands, script prints only `$second`

```
$first = $(Get-ADDomain | Select-Object InfrastructureMaster, RIDMaster, PDCEmulator)
$second = $(Get-ADForest | Select-Object DomainNamingMaster, SchemaMaster)
echo $second
echo $first
```

The output:

```
DomainNamingMaster SchemaMaster
------------------ ------------
ad-srv.cma.local   ad-srv.cma.local
```

I think the problem is that these variables are of type PSCustomObject, and for some reason powershell can't output them sequentially. Is there any way to output both of them?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62735813/3156906 - Powershell is delaying output and collecting both objects to display together, but it’s deciding the column names for the table based on the first object, and the second object doesn’t have those properties. If you look closely there’s probably an extra blank row in the output coming from the second object. To fix it, force Powershell to output the objects independently… see link for workarounds.